# non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'int' to 'unsigned long long' in initializer list

Tags: c++, constructor, bitset

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
   int x =  4;
   int y = 2;
   const int cell = x/y;
   auto a = std::bitset<20>{cell}; //fails
   auto b = std::bitset<20>(cell); //works
}
```

Why does `std::bitset` not allow me to construct with curly braces here, but works with parenthesis construction? If `cell` was instead a `constexpr`, both would compile.

The compile error:

```
test.cpp:21:29: error: non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'int' to 'unsigned long long' in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing]
   auto a = std::bitset<20>{x*y}; //fails
                            ^~~
test.cpp:21:29: note: insert an explicit cast to silence this issue
   auto a = std::bitset<20>{x*y}; //fails
                            ^~~
                            static_cast<unsigned long long>( )
1 error generated.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The failing line uses list-initializing syntax:

```
auto a = std::bitset<20>{cell}; //fails
```

This syntax is defined in [Section 11.6.4](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf#subsection.11.6.4) of the C++17 standard. The relevant part:

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type `T` is defined as follows:
>
> ...
>
> (3.7) Otherwise, if `T` is a class type, constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated and the best one is chosen through overload resolution (16.3, 16.3.1.7). **If a narrowing conversion (see below) is required to convert any of the arguments, the program is ill-formed.**
>
> ...
>
> A narrowing conversion is an implicit conversion
>
> ...
>
> (7.4) from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to an integer type that cannot represent all the values of the original type, **except where the source is a constant expression whose value after integral promotions will fit into the target type**.

This gives us a better understanding of what is going on:

```
// Works, no narrowing check, implicit conversion.
std::bitset<20> a(2);
std::bitset<20> b(-1);
std::bitset<20> c(cell); 

// Works, 2 can be converted without narrowing
std::bitset<20> d{2};

// Fails, -1 cannot be converted without narrowing
std::bitset<20> e{-1};

// Fails, compiler does not understand cell can be converted without narrowing
std::bitset<20> f{cell};
```

In your program, the compiler does not understand that `cell` is a constant expression. It checks the available constructors for `std::bitset` and sees it has to convert from `int` to `unsigned long long`. It thinks that `int` could be potentially be negative, therefore we have a narrowing conversion.

We can fix this by making `cell` a `constexpr`, which is stronger than `const`. Whereas `const` only means that the value should not be changed, `constexpr` means the value is available at compile time:

```
  constexpr int x = 4;
  constexpr int y = 2;
  constexpr int cell = x / y;

  auto a = std::bitset<20>{cell}; // works
```

You could now ask why list-initialization does not allow for narrowing conversion. I cannot fully answer this. My understanding is that implicit narrowing is generally seen as undesirable because it can have unintended consequences, and that it was excluded for this reason.

Comment: Ah I didn't know that an `int` to an `unsigned long long` is a narrowing conversion. Is this because `int` can be negative? If it had been an unsigned `int` instead of plain `int`, it seems that the conversion would be widening rather than narrowing.

Comment: Right, it's narrowing because the negative values cannot be represented. Your original program compiles fine when using `unsigned int`.

Comment: @f9c69e9781fa194211448473495534 What? No, it's a narrowing conversion because on 99% of compilers, `int` is a 32-bit integer and `long long` is a 64-bit integer. Going from `signed` to `unsigned` isn't a narrowing conversion; the amount of bits required to represent a signed or unsigned version of any size integer is the same, the only difference is how those bits are interpreted. A signed 32-bit integer's last bit indicates whether or not the remaining 31 bits are negative, this is why the signed integer limit is 2147483648 rather than 4294967296 (2^31 vs 2^32), that's the only difference.

Comment: @Shayna I don't understand your point. My understanding of the C++ standard is that a narrowing conversion is about the representable range of values, not the number of bits required: "A narrowing conversion is an implicit conversion from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to an integer type that cannot represent all the
values of the original type" (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3035.pdf#page=218). An unsigned type cannot represent a signed value.

Comment: @f9c69e9781fa194211448473495534 I was under the impression that a narrowing conversion means trying to fit the data from one type into a narrower type: a type that cannot logically contain the original data because it's simply too short, e.g. 32>16, 16>8, etc, causing the overflowing bits to be cut off - which is not the case when going from signed>unsigned. What I did not know is that the standard extends that definition to loss of sign conversions. When I try to compile it, the compiler complains of two narrowing conversions, the long long>int and the signed>unsigned. My bad! You're right.